# Slight design problem with Roles, Rules and Profile2 on my site

Tags: rules, users, flags

I'm a little stuck with the registration flow on my site. What I have is a multi-user environment, where each user can, but does not have to, create a secondary/Profile2 "shop" profile.

Now I don't want to just expose the Profile2 shop type to everyone. So I've set up a shopkeeper role, and would like to somehow allow users to request or opt into the role.
This isn't for security or anything. It just doesn't look professional having the menu link available to users who don't want or need the profile. Also, some newbie is bound to get curious and enter random crap, which will later mess with the display of their content.

My solution was to use a flag on the user page, which triggers a rule to promote the user, but the problem is; there's no Flag option to prevent users from being able to flag other user's accounts. Unless I use a page template to hide the flag link, but that's a perhaps a little too hacky, and as far as I understand, doesn't actually disable the link.

All I really want is some sort of link or checkbox somewhere(preferably on the user-page) saying, "I have a shop, lemme create a profile". So if anyone has a suggestion for my issue, it would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward way to do it.

1. Create a field (boolean) on the user account manage fields page.  Assign it useful label such as "I want to run a store" etc.
2. Create a rule to add the role as follows:

**Event** After saving user account **AND** After updating an existing user account

**Conditions** Data comparison (user account field value) == yes **AND** User has role (*store*) NOT

**Actions**
Add user role (*store*)

And create another rule to remove the role:

**Event** After updating an existing user account

**Conditions** Data comparison (user account field value) account-unchanged == yes **AND** data comparison (user account field value) account == yes

**Actions** Remove user role (*store*)

This should let the users check the box and then the role will automatically be toggled on or off.